# Enable binary logging MySQL

Tags: mysql, logging, binary

How exactly can I enable binary logging on MySQL server. Conf.file? Server Startup Parameter? If possible give me an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can start the server with the `--log-bin` option.

The MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/binary-log.html) will cover the details if you need more information.

Comment: I examine the documentation and I try different combinations of --log-bin with mysqld but I am not sure I proceed. So could someone please give an example

Comment: Executing mysqld with the --log-bin option should be enough. Is that not working?

Comment: Here is what I did.
I stop the service with net stop mysql
Then on command line I type mysqld --log-bin
Then nothing happened. Just cursor goes to new line and waits for something.
Then I try to start to service from MySQL Administrator but it gave me error. "Pluging FEDERATED is disabled' and service did not start.
As a summary I think it is not working.